# I am having problem with sklearn.cluster and KMeans

Tags: cluster-computing, k-means, sklearn-pandas, drop, capstone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M4CS.jpg)

This is the issue I am having for now

Comment: Please try running again by uncommenting the first line of code.

Comment: Since the suggestion worked, I have moved my comment to the answer section. Please accept it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In the future, please paste code, not pictures of code.  Paste the code in, select it, and then click the `{}` widget.  This will shift it right 4 spaces causing it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try running again by uncommenting the first line of code.